# Why "this" is undefined in function called via logical operator?

Tags: javascript

The following code ([codepen](https://codepen.io/s976/pen/ExxEvpo?editors=0012)) doesn't work.

```
"use strict"; //without strict "this" works, but it refers to window object

let person = {
  name : "Shimon",
  logName : function(){
    //console.log("test") //this works
    console.log(this.name); //doesn't work
  }
};

//person.logName(); //works
(false || person.logName)(); //doesn't work. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I want to understand why.
When I call `(false || person.logName)();` I suppose to call `person.logName()`, and it indeed called.
So why I cannot use `this` inside this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Instead of logging this name. You can actually return it. There might be problems with before es2015 standard where you refered to this as self. So generate es2015 method instead person = { name:"Simon", logname(){return this.name}}

Comment: @bhspencer It seems to be a very global question. I cannot find a point there. I will be very grateful, if you will specify a more precise manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are 4 rules for the JavaScript engine to determine the `this` reference.

1. ***New Bound***: Was the current function called using the `new` keyword
2. ***Explicit Binding***: Was the function called using `Function#call` or `Function#apply`.
3. ***Implicit Binding***: Was the function directly on its owning object?
4. ***Default***: If in strict mode `undefined` otherwise `global`

In your case `person.logName()` falls under the 3rd category so the `this` reference is set to the value of `person`.
But in the other case, the line `(false || person.logName)()` is equivalent to `var x = false || person.logName; x();`. That is because you are using an expression to get the function and thus the context is lost.
So you either need to use `person.logName()` or `(false || person.logName).call(person)`

Here is a more complex example:

```js
var actionMap = {
  0: function() {
    console.log(this === actionMap ? "actionMap" : "global");
  },
  1: function() {
    console.log(this === actionMap ? "actionMap" : "global");
  },
};

function other() {
  console.log(this === actionMap ? "actionMap" : "global");
}

actionMap[0](); // works
(actionMap[0])(); // works, brackets get ignored
(actionMap[0] || actionMap[1])(); // context is lost in the expression
(actionMap[2] || actionMap[1])(); // context is lost in the expression
(actionMap[2] || actionMap[1]).call(actionMap); // works, context is called explicitly

var boundOther = other.bind(actionMap);
(boundOther || actionMap[1])(); // function is bound
```

As you can see in this example, the context is lost even though both functions are owned by the same object. Since the function that gets called is derived by an expression and is not immediately called on its owning object.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply how Javascript semantics behave. Unless you call the method from the object it is attached to `this` cannot be resolved in the function scope.

Your example of:

```
(false || person.logName)();
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
var func = person.logName;
func();
```

Here you can visually see that there is an intermediate step where `logName()` is detached from `person`. This has a side effect of removing the `this` context.

---

There are ways to enforce the `this` context on "detached" functions. One of them being [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) which enables the binding of `this` to any function.

```
(false || person.logName.bind(person))();
```

Here a new function is created with `person` bound as `this` to achieve the desired behavior. Alternatively you could use [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to avoid creating a new function.

```
(false || person.logName).call(person);
```

This works in your contrived use-case, but it may not fit into your real use-case as you will need to pass different objects as the `this` parameter when the functions you "detach" are not from the same object.

Answer (score -1):

***this*** works on instantiated classes/functions. In your case you have to treat the object as static like:

```
let person = {
  name : "Shimon",
  logName : function(){
    console.log(person.name);
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want this behavior you can either use classes or prototypal inherintance

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  logName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

or

```js
function person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

person.prototype.logName = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

```
let shimon = new Person("Shimon");
shimon.logName()  // >> Shimon
```