# jQuery - Can't use replaceWith() function - Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, replace, replacewith

after a call with Axios, I want to replace the current item with a new one. I proceed like this:

```js
var replacedElement = "<span class='float-right' aria-hidden='true'>" +
            "<i class='fas fa-check icon-color'></i>" +
            "</span>";

        axios.post(url).then(function (response) {
           $(this).replaceWith($.parseHTML(replacedElement));
        });
```

But I have the following error : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`

My `$(this)` references a `span` element :

[image]

So I don't understand why I have this error

Comment: Have you added a `console.log(this)` inside the `then` function, because I' pretty sure that `this` won't refer to the same object? If that is the issue try storing `this` in a variable like `var self = this` and use `self` instead of `this` inside the `then` function.

Comment: You are right. When I made a `console.log ($(this))`, I did it before calling axios. Well done and thank you! :)

Comment: I've added a proper answer, with a couple of solutions and a link for understanding how `this` gets calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a `this` related error and not a jQuery one. You can check how `this` gets calculated on this [other answer I've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719710/why-this-is-undefined-in-function-called-via-logical-operator/58720195#58720195).

There are 3 simple ways to solve your problem.

1. Storing `this` in a variable (a common name is `self`)

```
var self = this;
axios.post(url).then(function(response) {
  $(self).replaceWith($.parseHTML(replacedElement));
});
```

2. Using [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to make sure `this` won't change

```
axios.post(url).then((function(response) {
  $(this).replaceWith($.parseHTML(replacedElement));
}).bind(this));
```

3. Using [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that don't alter the `arguments` and `this` (won't work in older browsers)

```
axios.post(url).then((response) => $(this).replaceWith($.parseHTML(replacedElement)));
```